# why is find on jquery ajax response ignoring ul elements

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

I have an ajax call that returns the below html. I want to parse it and construct a select box with corresponding items. Here (with `$(document)`) it works just fine,

```js
    sel = $('<select>').attr({id: 'archive', title: 'date/times as stored on the server'}).addClass('dt-button')
    $(document).find('ul li').each(function(k,v){
        txt = $(v).text()
        if (txt.match(/.*\.json/)){
            sel.prepend($('<option>').attr({value: `archive/${txt}`}).text(txt.replace('.json', '')))
        }
    })
    sel.prepend($('<option>').attr({value: 'latest.json', selected:'selected'}).text('latest'))
    $('body').append(sel)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Directory listing for /data/archive/</title>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Directory listing for /data/archive/</h1>
<hr>
<ul>
<li><a href=".gitkeep">.gitkeep</a></li>
<li><a href="2024-02-23.tgz">2024-02-23.tgz</a></li>
<li><a href="2024-02-24.tgz">2024-02-24.tgz</a></li>
<li><a href="2024-02-25_00-00-01.json">2024-02-25_00-00-01.json</a></li>
<li><a href="2024-02-25_00-10-01.json">2024-02-25_00-10-01.json</a></li>
<li><a href="2024-02-25_00-20-01.json">2024-02-25_00-20-01.json</a></li>
<li><a href="2024-02-25_00-30-01.json">2024-02-25_00-30-01.json</a></li>
<li><a href="2024-02-25_00-40-01.json">2024-02-25_00-40-01.json</a></li>
</ul>
<hr>
</body>
</html>
```

But when I do it on an actual ajax response:

```
$.ajax('data/archive/').done(function(data) {
    sel = $('<select>').attr({id: 'archive', title: 'date/times as stored on the server'}).addClass('dt-button')
    $(data).find('ul li').each(function(k,v){
        txt = $(v).text()
        if (txt.match(/.*\.json/)){
            sel.prepend($('<option>').attr({value: `archive/${txt}`}).text(txt.replace('.json', '')))
        }
    })
    sel.prepend($('<option>').attr({value: 'latest.json', selected:'selected'}).text('latest'))
    $('#data-archive').append(sel)
})
```

it doesnt work, as the `find` returns 0 items. it works only when i remove the `ul` from the selector and just leave `li` (or `li a`).
Can someone explain why?

```
$(data).filter('ul').find('li a').each(function(){console.log($(this).text())})
```

this also works...

so basically only the `'ul li'` selector doesnt work

Comment: Have you checked `data` really contains `ul` tag.

Comment: this also works `$($.parseHTML(data).filter(function(x){ return x.tagName == 'UL' })).children('li').each(function(){console.log($(this).text())})`